# javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException:

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

```
javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException: //C:/Sources/Applications/eCS/web/src/main/webapp/resources/components/transactionDisplay.xhtml @21,113 id="#{cc.attrs.showSubAccounts eq 'true' ? 'table':'table1'}" javax.el.ELException: //C:/Sources/Applications/eCS/web/src/main/webapp/common/accountactivity/AccountTransacations.xhtml @99,106 showSubAccounts="#{transactionModel.hasSubAccountTransactions(usb.csb.account.transactions)}": java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getObject(TagAttributeImpl.java:328)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getValue(TagAttributeImpl.java:292)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.assignUniqueId(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:359)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:156)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:116)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:133)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:180)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:117)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:94)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.composite.ImplementationHandler.apply(ImplementationHandler.java:77)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:94)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:89)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:149)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.CompositeComponentTagHandler.applyCompositeComponent(CompositeComponentTagHandler.java:347)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.CompositeComponentTagHandler.applyNextHandler(CompositeComponentTagHandler.java:184)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:180)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:117)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:94)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:134)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:180)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:117)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:94)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:162)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:89)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:304)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:364)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:343)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:197)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.IncludeHandler.apply(IncludeHandler.java:104)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:94)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:175)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:392)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:363)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:104)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:94)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:164)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:94)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:89)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:94)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:304)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:364)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:343)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:197)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:151)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:89)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:149)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:740)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:96)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:135)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:309)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
    at com.ads.retail.application.ecs.filter.ECSDisableDynamicClientCache.doFilter(ECSDisableDynamicClientCache.java:33)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: javax.el.ELException: //C:/Sources/Applications/eCS/web/src/main/webapp/common/accountactivity/AccountTransacations.xhtml @99,106 showSubAccounts="#{transactionModel.hasSubAccountTransactions(usb.csb.account.transactions)}": java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$AttributesMap.get(UIComponentBase.java:2228)
    at com.sun.faces.el.CompositeComponentAttributesELResolver$ExpressionEvalMap.get(CompositeComponentAttributesELResolver.java:341)
    at javax.el.MapELResolver.getValue(MapELResolver.java:164)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:173)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:200)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstPropertySuffix.getValue(AstPropertySuffix.java:53)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:67)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstEqual.getValue(AstEqual.java:21)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstChoice.getValue(AstChoice.java:27)
    at org.jboss.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ContextualCompositeValueExpression.getValue(ContextualCompositeValueExpression.java:153)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:106)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getObject(TagAttributeImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getValue(TagAttributeImpl.java:292)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.assignUniqueId(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:359)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:156)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:117)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:134)
    ... 68 more

Caused by: javax.el.ELException: //C:/Sources/Applications/eCS/web/src/main/webapp/common/accountactivity/AccountTransacations.xhtml @99,106 showSubAccounts="#{transactionModel.hasSubAccountTransactions(usb.csb.account.transactions)}": java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:111)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$AttributesMap.get(UIComponentBase.java:2226)
    ... 85 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ads.retail.application.ecs.model.TransactionModel.hasSubAccountTransactions(TransactionModel.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor911.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:328)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:273)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstMethodSuffix.getValue(AstMethodSuffix.java:59)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:67)
    at org.jboss.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:106)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$AttributesMap.get(UIComponentBase.java:2226)
    at com.sun.faces.el.CompositeComponentAttributesELResolver$ExpressionEvalMap.get(CompositeComponentAttributesELResolver.java:341)
    at javax.el.MapELResolver.getValue(MapELResolver.java:164)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:173)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:200)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstPropertySuffix.getValue(AstPropertySuffix.java:53)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:67)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstEqual.getValue(AstEqual.java:21)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstChoice.getValue(AstChoice.java:27)
    at org.jboss.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ContextualCompositeValueExpression.getValue(ContextualCompositeValueExpression.java:153)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:106)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getObject(TagAttributeImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getValue(TagAttributeImpl.java:292)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.assignUniqueId(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:359)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:156)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:116)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:133)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:180)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:116)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:94)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.composite.ImplementationHandler.apply(ImplementationHandler.java:77)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:94)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:89)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:79)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:148)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.CompositeComponentTagHandler.applyCompositeComponent(CompositeComponentTagHandler.java:347)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.CompositeComponentTagHandler.applyNextHandler(CompositeComponentTagHandler.java:184)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:180)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:116)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:94)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:133)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:180)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:116)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:94)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:162)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:89)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:79)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:304)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:363)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:342)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:196)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.IncludeHandler.apply(IncludeHandler.java:104)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:94)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:174)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:392)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:363)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:104)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:94)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:163)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:94)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:89)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:94)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:79)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:304)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:363)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:342)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:196)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:151)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:89)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:79)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:148)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:740)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:96)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:135)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:309)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at com.ads.retail.application.ecs.filter.ECSDisableDynamicClientCache.doFilter(ECSDisableDynamicClientCache.java:32)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    ... 9 more

2011-12-09 16:58:45 RunTimeExceptionHandler [ERROR] Detailed Message...
//C:/Sources/Applications/eCS/web/src/main/webapp/resources/components/transactionDisplay.xhtml @21,113 id="#{cc.attrs.showSubAccounts eq 'true' ? 'table':'table1'}" javax.el.ELException: //C:/Sources/Applications/eCS/web/src/main/webapp/common/accountactivity/AccountTransacations.xhtml @99,106 showSubAccounts="#{transactionModel.hasSubAccountTransactions(usb.csb.account.transactions)}": java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I am not able to understand the reason of this exception. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Please show the entire stacktrace. The EL evaluation failed due to a `NullPointerException`. But its root cause is missing in the stacktrace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always look at the bottommost root cause for the real root cause of the exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ads.retail.application.ecs.model.TransactionModel.hasSubAccountTransactions(TransactionModel.java:57)
```

In line 57 of `TransactionModel` class, inside the `hasSubAccountTransactions` method, you're trying to reference an object which is *actually* `null`. E.g.

```
Object someObject = null;
someObject.doSomething(); // NullPointerException!
```

To fix this, just make sure that it is **not** null, or add an `if` check to bypass the invocation if it's `null`.